# How to list all the tasks in camunda based on process definition key

Tags: bpmn, camunda, business-process-management

I want to get all the ongoing and future tasks if it's based on process instance id. Incase of definition,need to get all the tasks from camunda bpmn

I'm aware of

1. Get the bpm xml file and parse it to fetch all tasks
2. Bpmn model api

Comment: Are you looking for a REST call, or are you working with the Java-API?

Comment: @JanGalinski Thanks for your response.I'm using Rest API and Java, found solution by myself. Answer I posted in the same post.